# How to animate the camera to a specified location in Google Maps v2 for Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm having trouble moving the Google Maps camera back to the initial position. Basically, I have a home button on the Actionbar. If a user scrolls around the map, and taps the Home button, I would like the camera to move back to its original location.

I get the original coordinates using `googleMap.getCameraPosition().target`, but the camera doesn't move.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    LatLng initialLoc= mMap.getCameraPosition().target;

    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(initialLoc);
    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

    mMap.moveCamera(update);
    mMap.animateCamera(zoom);

    return true;
}
```

map.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context="org.test"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        map:cameraTargetLat="xxx.xxx"
        map:cameraTargetLng="xxx.xxx"
        map:cameraZoom="15"
        map:mapType="normal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Whenever the user selects the option, you are using

```
LatLng initialLoc= mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
```

to get the supposedly initial location, which is wrong!
[mMap.getCameraPosition().target](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition#target) returns the location that the camera is pointing at. You should store the lat long in the `onCreate()` of the activity or some other place as per your other code, and then use the same in `onOptionItemSelected()`.

Btw you can combine the zoom and lat long in a single statement as follows.

```
    LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng); //Store these lat lng values somewhere. These should be constant.
    CameraUpdate location = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            coordinate, 15);
    mMap.animateCamera(location);
```

**UPDATE**

I dont really know as to how accurate that'd be or when to call it. But you could use the same code

```
LatLng initialLoc= mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
```

Instead call this once in your `onCreate()`, or `onResume()` and then store it there. Then next time in your `optionsItemSelected()` use those values. Although, why don't you simply store those values that you defined in your xml in java code and then use it?

Comment: You are right! How would I be able to get my camera's initial coordinates. My camera's initial coordinates was defined in my .xml using `cameraTargetLat` and `cameraTargetLat`. How can I retrieve that programmatically?

Comment: Which xml are you talking about?

Comment: I updated my post, I like to retrieve the camera's target lat and long without defining new constants for the coordinates. Is it possible to retrieve these values from the .xml programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

```
     LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());  
     MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions(); 
     markerOptions.position(latLng); 
     markerOptions.title(totalAddress); //Here Total Address is address which you want to show on marker
     mMap.clear();


    markerOptions.icon(
    BitmapDescriptorFactory
   .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)); 

     markerOptions.getPosition(); 
     mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions); 
     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); 
     mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(coordinate);
                    markerOptions.title(placeName); //Here Total Address is address which you want to show on marker
                    mGoogleMap.clear();
                    markerOptions.icon(
                            BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));

                    markerOptions.getPosition();
                    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(coordinate));
                    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
```